# Normal Coordinates for Complex Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

I am searching for a good reference that carefully discusses the construction of standard Riemann normal coordinates but for complex manifolds (with an integrable complex structure), Kähler manifolds also of interest. Any suggestions?

Comment: The usual notion of normal coordinates exists on a hermitian complex manifold if and only if it is Kähler. See, for example, Griffiths/Harris.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i will check Griffiths and Harris when i get to the office tomorrow morning

Comment: can you give me a page number or section?

Comment: Bottom of p. 107 to the top of p. 109. :)

Comment: your comment is useful, thank you!